# Laravel select default disabled option

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, frameworks

That i'm trying todo to disable some option in my select form.
I'm using laravel 5.
Code looks like:

```
{!! Form::smartSelectForeign('country_id', trans('app.object_country')) !!}
```

Trying to add "Please select" option and trying disable to choose "Please select" option:

```
{!! Form::smartSelectForeign('country_id', null, array('default' => 'Please Select')) !!}
```

Some thing like that: [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/Yfs4u/1/).
But dosn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: anyone can help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what that `smartSelectForeign` method is.

But if you are using [the laravel collective form](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) package you can set a placeholder like this:

```
{!! Form::select('country_id', trans('app.object_country'), null, ['placeholder' => 'Please Select'] ) !!}
```

So for your your custom method probably like this:

```
{!! Form::smartSelectForeign('country_id', trans('app.object_country'), null, ['placeholder' => 'Please Select'] ) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have a solution but it will require some client side validation and it is working for me in laravel 5.7

```
{{FORM::SELECT('country_id', null, array('' => 'Please Select', 'item'=>'item','item1'=>'item1'))}}
```

Now add javascript

```
let country = $('#country_id').val();
if(country == ''){alert('country cannot be empty');}
```

I hope this works for you